# Vim and Gvim - Change color for cursorline line numbers

Tags: vim, colors, gvim

I have downloaded and installed the [blueshift](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3328) colorscheme for vim/gvim.

This highlights the current line with cursorline, which is what I want, however the background color of the line numbers column is changed to "white".

- How can I change this color?

I would like to change it to be a more subtle color, perhaps something close to `#c0d0e0` which is the background color of the "non-current-line" line numbers.

To help illustrate my description, please see the attached image below.

[image: Screenshot]

The "red" is ok, but I would like to change the "white" background to another color.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is controlled by the `CursorLineNr` highlight group. It's a recent (Vim 7.4) addition; the blueshift colorscheme does not have a definition for that.

You can change it like that (after the `:colorscheme blueshift` command):

```
:highlight CursorLineNr gui=bold guifg=DarkRed guibg=#c0d0e0
```

Comment: That's really cool. Thanks. How did you manage to find this information? I have a few more questions to ask but it would probably be better if I could just figure it out myself (assuming that you have a reference for this info).

Comment: You can see all highlight groups via `:hi`. In the Vim help, this is documented at `:help highlight-groups`. I remembered this particular group name because I follow the Vim development quite closely.